# Replacing Strings with .htaccess in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to edit my `.htaccess` file so that this string:

> https://example.com/haathumb.php?var=400x300/src/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/brain-training-game-show-app-improves-memory.jpg

Is replaced with this replaced with this string:

> https://example.com/thumb/400x300/src/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/brain-training-game-show-app-improves-memory.jpg

To sum up I need to replace `haathumb.php?var=` with `thumb` in a string using `.htaccess`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

A redirect from haathumb.php?var=... to thumb/... then?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)var=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^haathumb\.php$ /thumb/%1? [L,R=permanent]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `.htaccess` code below to make [haathumb](https://github.com/haaking/haathumb) work correctly:

```
# BEGIN haathumb rewrite
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^thumb/(.*) /haathumb.php?var=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
# END haathumb rewrite
```